# How can I give my chatbot short-term memory using redis when deployed on azure?

Tags: spring-boot, azure, redis, openai-api

I have a chatbot built on spring-boot that interacts with openAI's chat completions API to generate answers based on user queries. The chatbot interacted fine, however, it doesn't store any context. To counter this, I developed an in-memory context by initializing an array that would store the user input and the response, and append it to the messages that will form part of OpenAI's Chat Completions next query. However, after deploying the application on azure, I quickly realised that every time someone submitted a query the page would refresh without storing it into the array. This led me to make use of a session Management tool such as Redis. However, I am very new to the tech stack, and I am struggling to use it to solve my problem, any help would be great!

Logic is as follows. `/Products` get a POST request with user input. User input is stored and other logic persists throughout this page and a list of products are generated and sent through to the chatcontroller class to the chat method that will used as part of messages sent to the chat completions API.

**ProductsController Class:**

```java
String response = chatController.chat(productList);
        System.out.println("Response: \n" +  response);
```

**ChatController Class:**

```java
public String chat(@RequestParam List<String> messages) {

        List<Message> messageList = new ArrayList<>();

        ArrayList<ConversationRecord> conversationRecords = new ArrayList(ConversationService.getConversationRecords)

        if (conversationRecords == null){
            conversationRecords = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        //check if there has been a saved conversation
        if (conversationRecords != null)
        {
            for (ConversationRecord record: conversationRecords)
            {
                messageList.add(new Message("system",record.getUserQuery()));
                messageList.add(new Message("assistant",record.getChatResponse()));
            }
        }
        if (conversationRecords.size() > 10){
            conversationRecords.remove(0);
        }

        messageList.add(new Message("system", "You are a helpful assistant!")
```

As can be seen here I am originally storing the previous conversation record in the `arrayList`, and as stated that needs to change now that I am deploying the application onto azure. Any help on the matter would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Off topic: you might want to try [redis-llm](https://github.com/sewenew/redis-llm) which integrate Redis and OpenAI API, and you can use it for chatting with a long chat history or searching your private data. Disclaimer: I'm the author of this redis module.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a service class that will manage conversation history and interact with Redis. This service will handle saving and retrieving conversation records.

Here I created **Azure cache for redis** to store the conversation history in Redis and retrieve conversation history when needed.

**application.properties:**

[image]

- Whenever a user interacts with the chatbot, you save their query and the response to Redis. When you need to retrieve the conversation history in the `ChatController`, you can fetch it from Redis using the `ConversationService`. This approach ensures that the conversation context is maintained across different instances and requests in your Azure-deployed Spring Boot application.

Here I set-up by creating a service class that will manage conversation history and interact with Redis. This service will handle saving and retrieving conversation records.

**ConversationService:**

```java
@Service
public class ConversationService {
    private final String REDIS_KEY = "conversationHistory";

    @Autowired
    private StringRedisTemplate redisTemplate;

    public void saveConversationRecord(ConversationRecord record) {
        redisTemplate.opsForList().rightPush(REDIS_KEY, record.toString());
    }

    public List<String> getConversationRecords() {
        return redisTemplate.opsForList().range(REDIS_KEY, 0, -1);
    }
}
```

The application is able to connect with the redis.

[image]

Then update your `ProductsController` and `ChatController` to save and retrieve conversation records.

**ProductsController:**

```java
@RestController
public class ProductsController {
    @Autowired
    private ChatController chatController;

    @Autowired
    private ConversationService conversationService;

    @PostMapping("/Products")
    public String processProductQuery(@RequestParam List<String> messages) {
    
        String userQuery = "User's Query"; // Replace with the user's query  
        String response = "Chatbot's Response"; // Replace with the chatbot's response

        ConversationRecord record = new ConversationRecord(userQuery, response);  
        conversationService.saveConversationRecord(record);  
  
        // Call chat method in ChatController  
        String chatResponse = chatController.chat(messages);  
  
        // ... your response logic  
  
        return chatResponse;
    }
}
```

**ChatController:**

```
@RestController  
public class ChatController {  
    @Autowired  
  private ConversationService conversationService;  
  
  @GetMapping("/chat/history")  
    public List<String> getConversationHistory() {  
        // Retrieve conversation history from Redis  
  return conversationService.getConversationRecords();  
  }
```

Retrieve the conversation history by sending a GET request to `/chat/history`.